# Bootstrap overwrites css-styling

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I implemented a payment that uses a gateway from ACI. I discovered that bootstrap overwrites the css that comes with the apple pay button from ACI.

This is what my code looks like:

```
import * as React from "react"
import {useEffect} from "react";
import {FaRegCreditCard} from'react-icons/fa';
import "../../styles/shoppingBag.css";


export function RenderPaymentScript({checkoutId,orderId}) {
    const id = localStorage.getItem("restaurantUid");
    const isSafari = window.safari !== undefined;

    useEffect(async ()=>{
        window.wpwlOptions={
            applePay: {
                displayName: "example",
                total: { label: "example" },
                style: "black",
                currencyCode: "EUR"
            },
            style: "plain",
            locale:"DE",
            
        };
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src =`${process.env.REACT_APP_PAYMENT_URL}${checkoutId}`;
        script.async = true;
        document.body.appendChild(script);

        return () => {
            document.body.removeChild(script);
        }
    },[]);

    return (
        <div className="reset">
            <form action={`${process.env.REACT_APP_URL}/checkout/${id}/${orderId}/`} className="paymentWidgets" data-brands="APPLEPAY"/>
            <form action={`${process.env.REACT_APP_URL}/checkout/${id}/${orderId}/`} className="paymentWidgets" data-brands="GOOGLEPAY"/>
                <div className="paymentBox">
                    <text>Kreditkarte</text>
                    <FaRegCreditCard size={25} color={'#6C5AF2'} className="paymentIcon"/>
                </div>
            <form action={`${process.env.REACT_APP_URL}/checkout/${id}/${orderId}/`} className="paymentWidgets" data-brands="VISA MASTER"/>
        </div>
    )
}


export default RenderPaymentScript;
```

This is what causes the overwriting of the code:
[image]

And this is how the button looks at the moment:
[image]

I don't know how I can overwrite bootstrap again or prevent bootstrap to be executed in this function.

This is how I tried to reset it:

```
.reset {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    appearance:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try more specific selector including more locators, f.e.:

```
button[type="button"].reset {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
```

or use !important, if it won't help:

```
button[type="button"].reset {
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    -moz-appearance: none important;
    appearance: none important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it didn't work. The button still looks the same...

Comment: You should check that in devtools, why bootstrap rules are placing higher than custom css rules?